# Query Azure Storage Account metrics from Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

New to Azure and Powershell. I used the following script to connect to my Azure subscription and storage account.

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsAzure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile 'C:\AZURE_POWERSHELL\DETAILS.publishsettings'
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName subname -CurrentStorageAccount storagename
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName subname
```

I wish to query the storage account now to:

- Count the number of containers in Blob.
- Count the number of documents these containers.
- Return the file storage size of all documents.
- Return the file storage size of documents with a specified date range.

Is this possible from Azure Powershell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get number of containers

```
(Get-AzureStorageContainer).Count
```

Get number of blobs in container

```
(Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "ContainerName").Count
```

Not sure if you want file sizes for each individual file or an aggregate size.

Individual file sizes can be shown with `Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "ContainerName"` which list a `Length` attribute for each blob. `Length` is the blob size in bytes.

Total file size can be retrieved by doing this

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "ContainerName" | %{ $_.Length } | measure -Sum
```

To get files that were last modified in a specific date range just do

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "ContainerName" | where { $_.LastModified -gt (Get-Date -Date "specific date") -and $_.LastModified -lt (Get-Date -Date "specific date") }
```

Comment: Thank you Casey , works perfectly. Cannot up vote until rep = 15 sorry.